# some of the links withing Micro-Feeds has wrong href

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I have installed a brand new SharePoint 2013 test environment and testing around. When you go to NewsFeed (previously called my content), you find a web part (I think) which shows who follows who/what. some of the links within this web part are wrong. I mean when you hover over the names the href of link contains the name of Server instead of host header (for example instead of subdomain.domian.com it shows testSrv01 which is the name of the server and is wrong). so when you click on those links that contains the name of the server the browser shows "The page cannot be found....". thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to probably check your Alternate Access Mappings and make sure the default one is the one you want to use.